# Backbone's Router.execute(callback, args, name) method gets undefined name

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I try to implement router which simply show view from defined map according to route's name.

This is my router:

```
/*global define*/

define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/user',
  'views/header',
  'views/login',
  'views/registration'
], function ($, _, Backbone, UserModel, HeaderView, LoginView, RegistrationView) {
  'use strict';

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    models: {
      userModel: {}
    },

    staticViews: {
      header: {}
    },

    views: {
      login: {},
      registration: {}
    },

    routes: {
      'login': 'login',
      'registration': 'registration'
    },

    initialize: function () {
      this.models.userModel = new UserModel();
      this.staticViews.header = new HeaderView({el: 'nav#header', model: this.models.userModel})
      this.views.login = new LoginView({el: 'section#lifeline-login', model: this.models.userModel});
      this.views.registration = new RegistrationView({el: 'section#lifeline-registration', model: this.models.userModel});

      this.hideAllViews();
      this.navigate('login', {trigger: true, replace: true});
    },

    execute: function (callback, args, name) {
      this.hideAllViews();
      console.log(name);  //undefined
      console.log(callback);

      var view = this.views[name];
      if (view) {
        view.$el.show();
      }
      if (callback) callback.apply(this, args);
    },

    hideAllViews: function () {
      _.each(this.views, function (view) {
        view.$el.hide();
      });
    },

    login: function () {
    },

    registration: function () {
    }

  })
  return Router ;
});
```

**The main problem is undefined name in execute method.**

I'm not sure is this the best way to do this. Another idea which comes to my mind is something like that, but it's little tricky:

```
 routes: {
  ':name': 'change',
},

change: function (name) {
  this.hideAllViews();
  var view = this.views[name];
  if (view) {
    view.$el.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

#### You have a pre 1.2.0 Backbone, because

- in latest version the `name` argument cannot be `undefined` but an empty string and
- passing it into `execute()` [was introduced with `62320783`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/623207831ec09687f9cd9fa3a461f88849b02578) which is contained in 1.2.0+

#### You manually create a route elsewhere using `route()` but missing to pass a handler name as 2nd argument

See [the code of the 1.3.3 router](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.3.3/backbone.js#L1495):

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
  if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
  if (_.isFunction(name)) {
    callback = name;
    name = '';
  }
  if (!callback) callback = this[name];
  var router = this;
  Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
    var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);
    if (router.execute(callback, args, name) !== false) {
      router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
      router.trigger('route', name, args);
      Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
    }
  });
  return this;
},
```

---

Update your Backbone or debug the cause of the undefined `name` by creating a breakpoint through the debugger in line 1 of `route()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ur backbone maybe too old!
At version 1.1.2,function execute has only 2 arguments,name is always null.

Comment: My version is 1.1.0 (default for yeoman backbone generator) and documentation still have three arguments http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute

Comment: Code of Backbone is readable.My suggest is to start with document.And debug with source code when u meet some problem.